# How to select a row depending on the field value of that row

Tags: mysql

```
+---------+-------+
|value    |fruit  |
+---------+-------+
|0        |Orange |
+---------+-------+
|2        |Orange |
+---------+-------+
```

If there is a value 2 for Orange i have to select that row,if not select the row with value 0.

EDIT: Corrected typo in "Ornage". @Ysh correct?

Comment: your question is really not clear

Comment: @AshReva.Please see the table,first i've to check if there value 2 for Orange,if yes select that row with value 2 for Orange,if not select the row with value 0 for Orange.Hope i'm clear.

Comment: Well, yes, but are there always at max 2 rows per fruit? And please post what you've tried. It also makes things more clear. And more sample data would also be useful.

Comment: Why is this getting upvoted? There is no row with value 0 for 'Orange', and besides, this example is too minimal to be useful/meaningful.

Comment: You have to show us what you have tried. I think you want the 'Orange' for the maximum number of value. Is that right? This is just a query to do, so google it. Sometimes it is hard to find what we need when we don't know what to search, so, here is my hint: google: select max mysql you probably will figure it out.

Comment: Why's this so difficult to understand?.First check if there is a row with value 2 for Orange & Yes there is a row with value 2 in the Table above,Fetch that,if not fetch the one with value 0.I just want to know something like this can be done with mysql IF condition.Also i haven't tried anything.Just want to know if such a thing is possible with mysql

Comment: It is not difficult to understand at all. But this site is to help people that do some code and are having trouble with it. And answering you, `yes` it is possible I can think of at least 4 or 5 things you can do in a query to get what you want. We here dont just go for the answer to the OP because some guys are lazy regarding homework so, we are here not to do so for then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE 
fruit="ORANGE"
AND
(value =0 OR value=2)
ORDER BY value Desc
limit 1
```